# How to fix (Missing: any) in create-react-app with TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I call BookTracker component in my root App.tsx, with book={MY_MOCK},

```
type BookParamsTypes = {
  title: string;
  pubDate: number;
  //... rest
};

import { BookParamsTypes } from "./types/BookParamsTypes";

type BookTrackerProps = {
  book: BookParamsTypes[];
};

const BookTracker = ({ book }: BookTrackerProps) => (
//...
        <BookDetailed book={book}/>
//...
);
```

for the BookDetailed above i have an error message
**"JSX element type '{ book: BookParamsTypes[]; (Missing): any; }' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type '{ book: BookParamsTypes[]; (Missing): any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key - ts(2605)"**
how come this be? no clues

And then i cannot properly map inside BookDetailed

```
{book.map((item, i: number) => (
  // ..
      <BookTitle>{item.title}</BookTitle>
  // ... rest
  ))}
```

Linter doesnt understand book.map at all and also says **item implicitly has any type**...

For other reference,
here is my tsconfig:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "types": [],
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/sw-*.js",
    "src/idb.js"
  ]
}
```

and package.json

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.11",
    "@types/node": "11.13.6",
    "@types/react": "16.8.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.14",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.4"
  }
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "stylelint": "^10.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-react": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

Maybe i have some sort of tslint / config conflicts?
Can please some one help me figure it out?

Comment: How did you define `BookDetailed` ?

Comment: "const BookTracker = ({ book }: BookTrackerProps)" should be "const BookTracker = (book: BookTrackerProps)"

Comment: @NirWeber,
BookDetailed is

`type BookDetailedProps = {
  book: BookParamsTypes[];
};  
const BookDetailed = ({book}: BookDetailedProps) => (
  {book.map((item: any, i: number) => (
    <Container key={i}>
      <BookTitle>{item.title}</BookTitle>
     // ....
    </Container>
  ))}
);`

`code`

Comment: @NirWeber EDIT, ok, so i somehow fixed it!
seems like problem was in BookDetail - it had no <></> around map call inside

THANK YOU very much for giving your time to mu problem!

Comment: @BenSmith thank you for asnwer! but this syntax difference seem to have no impact on result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure `BookDetailed` component is defined correctly.